# What the difference between using Django redirect and HttpResponseRedirect?

Tags: python, django, redirect

Which is it better to use generally?

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect

Is there any advantage to writing:

```
return redirect(my_url)
```

over:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(my_url)
```

Or is it a direct alias? Is there any difference? Which is more pythonic/django-nic?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

There is a difference between the two:

In the case of `HttpResponseRedirect` the first argument can only be a `url`.

`redirect` which will *ultimately* return a `HttpResponseRedirect` can accept a `model`, `view`, or `url` as it's "to" argument. So it is a little more flexible in what it can "redirect" to.

I also like how `redirect` is shorter. So I'd use `redirect` over `HttpResponseRedirect`.

Both are fine to use though.

Answer (score 23):

From documentation -

> `redirect(to[, permanent=False], *args, **kwargs)` Returns an
>   `HttpResponseRedirect` to the appropriate URL for the arguments passed.

from the definition its the same. Thats what shortcuts are for. Both are one and the same.

shortcuts generally are written one level above the actual API's. So `redirect` encapsulates `HttpResponseRedirect` and `HttpResponsePermanentRedirect` with the arg `permanent=False`.

There is no major downside to using `HttpResponseRedirect` over `redirect`. Hope this clears it.