# How to pass dictionary of values when redirecting user to a url in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Below is the code from views.py where I am using `render_to_response` to direct the user to `done.html` along with a dictionary of variables. But, I actually want to direct the user to a url `/home_main/#signin_complete`and pass the dictionary of variables that are callable. Can someone please suggest if there is a way of doing this ?

```
def done(request):
    """Login complete view, displays user data"""
    scope = ' '.join(GooglePlusAuth.DEFAULT_SCOPE)

    return render_to_response('done.html', {
        'user': request.user,
        'plus_id': getattr(settings, 'SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_KEY', None),
        'plus_scope': scope
    }, RequestContext(request))
```

**EDIT**

My requirement is to render a second page (signin_complete) from a multipage html (home_main.html). Currently, I am achieving this by redirecting the user with `HttpResponseRedirect` as shown below. But, I would also like to pass a callable dictionary that I can use in the second page of the multipage html.

Here is a [link](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-rc.1/dist/demos/pages/) that gives more information of a multipage html under multipage template structure.

```
def done(request):
        """Login complete view, displays user data"""
        scope = ' '.join(GooglePlusAuth.DEFAULT_SCOPE)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home_main/#signin_complete')
```

Below is the dictionary that I would like to pass to the second page (sign_complete) in the multi page html.

```
            {
            'user': request.user,
            'plus_id': getattr(settings, 'SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_KEY', None),
            'plus_scope': scope
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django return redirect() with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters)

Comment: The answer to your question is at [redirect with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters). Also [difference in redirect/HttpRedirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304149/what-the-difference-between-using-django-redirect-and-httpresponseredirect) might clear things up. (I admit I didn't know this, either, before also searching for how to pass parameters in a HttpRedirect)

Answer (score 2):

The [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/) is the place to store data between requests.

```
# in done():
request.session['dict_to_save'] = my_dict_to_save
return redirect('/new/url/to/redirect/to')

# in the new view:
values_from_session = request.session.pop('dict_to_save', None)
```

Comment: I've looked at the session, from the link you have provided, but honestly didn't understand much. Would really appreciate if you could give a small example.

Comment: Appreciate your response, I kindly request you to have a look at the additional info I've aded under edit.

Comment: I don't really understand why you need to save that data. Two of the elements are constant, and can just as easily be calculated in the destination view, and the user is accessible via `request.user` in any case and doesn't need to be saved.

Comment: Instead of using `HttpResponseRedirect`, I would ideally want to use `render_to_response('page2 from home_main.html',{'user': request.user,'plus_id': getattr(settings, 'SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_KEY', None),'plus_scope': scope})`. I am unsure how to render_to_response page 2 from home_main.html. Sorry for the confusion that I've caused.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better if you would redirect request inside `done()` method, like the docs [advises](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.done) you to do.

This solves your issue as well, since you can define your own url to redirect to, [there's related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166850/1566605) of how to add hash tags when redirecting.

Comment: I've added more info under Edit to my question, to bring more clarity.